# How to handle svg imports (ES6) in rollup

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, rollup

If I'm importing an svg file into an ES6 module, how do I handle that in rollup? I currently have something like this (simple example of what I'm doing):

```
import next from '../assets/next.svg';
export default () => console.log('Here is some Svg: ! ', next);
```

And I have a rollup config that looks like this:

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';

export default {
  entry: 'src/app.js',
  dest: 'build/app.min.js',
  format: 'iife',
  sourceMap: 'inline',
  plugins: [
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
    }),
    resolve({
      jsnext: true,
      main: true,
      browser: true,
    }),
    commonjs(),
  ],
};
```

And then I get the following error:

> Could not resolve '../assets/next.svg' from
>   /home/magnferm/projects/slask/rollup-test/src/chill/index.js

There is nothing wrong with the path, but rollup doesn't seem to know how to handle svg-files. Is there a plugin I can use for that or do I have to treat it differently somehow?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a plugin for it. It's called **[@rollup/plugin-image](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/image#rollupplugin-image)** and it handles, among other formats, .svg imports:

```
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';

export default {
  entry: 'src/app.js',
  dest: 'build/appn.min.js',
  format: 'iife',
  sourceMap: 'inline',
  plugins: [
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
    }),
    resolve({
      jsnext: true,
      main: true,
      browser: true,
    }),
    commonjs(),
    image()
  ],
};
```

Comment: Hi, I still have a similar issue with this plugin: `Could not load /Users/stan/dev/projects/front-boilerplate/src/icons/baseline-delete_forever-24px.svg.js`
Why is rollup looking for a `svg.js` file?